# How to select all checkboxes in a column?

Tags: javascript, handsontable

Does anyone know how to select(check) all the check boxes in column of handsontable by checking the first check box of a particular column. I tried all the possible options to get it done but I,m not able to do it by any means.

Here is the code,

```
  function getCarData() {
    return [
      { available: true,available2: true,available3: true, comesInBlack: 'yes'},
      {available: false,available2: true,available3: true,available3: true, comesInBlack: 'yes'},
      { available: true,available2: true,available3: true, comesInBlack: 'no'},
      {available: false,available2: true,available3: true, comesInBlack: 'yes'},
      { available: false,available2: true,available3: true, comesInBlack: 'no'}
    ];
  }

  var example1 = document.getElementById('example1'),
    hot1;

  hot1 = new Handsontable(example1, {
    data: getCarData(),
    colHeaders: ['Available','Available2','Available3'],
    columns: [

      {
        data: 'available',
        type: 'checkbox'
      },{
        data: 'available2',
        type: 'checkbox'
      },{
        data: 'available3',
        type: 'checkbox'
      }
    ]
  });
```

Comment: Can you please provide html and put that on some fiddle...?

Comment: please submit your code to better understand the question

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of Handsontable, you can use document.querySelectorAll('table input[type="checkbox"]') to get a list of all check-boxes that are inside a table. Instead of table input[type="checkbox"], you can use any CSS selector like string.

Then what you would need to do is to iterate them and set checked = true, like this.

```
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('table tr td input[type="checkbox"]');
for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++)
    checkboxes[i].checked = true;
```

Comment: @ZekeDroid: can you please help me with this in the HOT table way?

Answer (score 0):

This is simple if you could use jquery

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkAll">Check All
<hr />
<input type="checkbox" id="checkItem">Item 1
<input type="checkbox" id="checkItem">Item 2
<input type="checkbox" id="checkItem">Item 3

$("#checkAll").click(function(){
    $('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a loop for that. You may add an id to your check all checkbox (or select it by name e.g. `"input[name='check-all']"`) like this:

```
$(document).on("click", "#toggleCheck", function() {
    $("table").find("input[type='checkbox']").prop("checked", "checked");
});
```

With this I'm selecting all checkboxes in the table but you can limit your selector by either selecting from a common ancestor or adding a class on the checkboxes you wish or adding a special attribute.